# c# / XNA 4.0- Move textures to give illusion of infinite plane

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, math, xna, xna-4.0

I've been having trouble implementing an algorithm to shift my textures given their positions and the cameras position. The first two pictures in the  image explain what I'm trying to accomplish, but I can't figure out how to move them accordingly. I had created a program once upon a time that did this, but I've gone and lost it. Any ideas?

If it helps any, the Cameras/Viewports width and height are the same as the textures' width and height. The goal is the get them to shift positions, giving the illusion of an infinite plane. (With out having to draw an infinite plane, lol.)

[image: The first two examples:]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a couple hours of trial and error, I finally figured out how to get the regions/textures/rectangles to move accordingly. For those who want the solution,

```
        if ((int)Math.Abs(region.X - camPos.X) > region.Width * 2)
        {
            region.X += region.Width * 2;
        }

        if (camPos.X < region.X - region.Width)
        {
            region.X -= region.Width * 2;
        }

        if ((int)Math.Abs(region.Y - camPos.Y) > region.Height * 2)
        {
            region.Y += region.Height * 2;
        }

        if (camPos.Y < region.Y - region.Height)
        {
            region.Y -= region.Height * 2;
        }
```

Where camPos is the camera position, and region is the region/texture/rectangle/whatever.

This code works for a 4 square region (2 regions by 2 regions). To change for more regions, simply change all the *2s to *3s or *4s for a 9 square region and 16 square region, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to move your regions, enough to decide where to draw them. Lets assume you have a terrain containing N*M blocks (in this case N=M=2), each of them are size of A*A (in this case the screen hase the same size, but this doesn't matter), and the Tiles are continously following each other.

```
int LeftColumn = Camera.X / A; // let it round to nearest lower int
int TopRow = Camera.Y / A;

LeftColumn = LeftColumn % N; // Calculate the first tile
TopRow = TopRow % M;

for (int i = LeftColumn+N; i < LeftColumn+2*N; i++)
  for (int l = TopRow+M; l < TopRow+2*M; l++)
  // you may check here if the tile is visible or not based on the screen size
  {
    Tile[i % N, l % M].Draw(i*A, l*A); // Or do whatever you like
  }
```

Is this clear?

Comment: I actually have no idea what your doing there... Xd I'm only using four rectangles, so it should be rather simple to move each to another location given the variables, but I'm not sure what order to calculate them in.

Comment: And I like how you down voted because I couldn't understand your answer. It's not like you replied to my comment. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything. My code works the way to calculate the tile for a given space in the world than the other way around. For example your camera looks somewhere in an imaginary grid, and calculates which "tile" would be there if you would move them. E.g. you have three tiles (0,1,2), which one would be on an imagined position of 8? (8 mod 3 = 2) Only it does it in 2D. Is that clear enough?